# To which variable object statements inside with are bind?

Tags: javascript, with-statement, scope-chain

```
function buildUrl() {
  var qs = "?debug=true";
  with(location){
    var url = href + qs;
  }
  return url;
}
buildUrl(); // it will work. WHY?
```

I am working through a "Professional JavaScript for Web Developers" by N. Zakas, and I came across this snippet. From my understanding `with` is a statement that augments scope chain by pushing, in this case, `location` object to the front.

It seems that `url` local variable is assigned to a function activation object. Why isn't it assigned to `location`?

Comment: What is a "function activation object"? What does it mean to 'bind a statement to a variable"? Anyway, `url` is a variable declared as a variable and would never be interpreted as a property of `location`.

Comment: @torazaburo http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/189973

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`with` adds the argument `location` for the purposes of lookup, but your `var url` is still hoisted to the containing function - i.e. `buildUrl` as you are creating a variable, not looking one up.

However, you should completely avoid `with`, [see the statement on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with).

Answer (score 0):

**The with statement is deprecated**

The use of the with statement is generally discouraged. 
It is forbidden in strict mode:

> function foo() { "use strict"; with({}); }
>
> SyntaxError: strict mode code may not contain 'with' statements Best
>   practice: Don’t use a with statement.

```
with(foo.bar.baz) {
    console.log("Hello "+first+" "+last);
}
```

Do use a temporary variable with a short name.

```
var b = foo.bar.baz; 
console.log("Hello "+b.first+" "+b.last);
```

Comment: This is not a question to the answer. I know that it is deprecated, but I am trying to understand the mechanism.

Comment: @PiotrekHryciuk Why are you trying to understand the mechanism of an obsolete construct that you cannot even use in a modern environment? Did you pick up this book in the used book pile? Find a new book quick.

Comment: @torazaburo got some recommendations? AFAIK this is the most complete book on js to date.

Comment: How could it be the most complete book when the most recent edition is four years old? it refers to ES5 as "new" and refers to ES6 as "what's coming in Harmony". It refers to the application cache which is not only obsoleted by service workers but was deprecated in HTML5.1, etc. etc. As I said.